# How to improve blocks start in athletics

Tags: technique, running, track-and-field

I'm try to improve my blocks start but for some reason I'm finding it hard. I'm quite tall but I good with jumping and improving my weights. Is there any drills I can try to improve this?

Answer (score 5):

Also try strengthening your quadriceps, since they are the main driving force in block starts. There's an exercise for improving your starting strides:
Stand with your toes touching the line, then slowly lean forward like you're going to fall on your nose (something like MJ in Smooth Criminal :) )
Lean until it's time to start running.

YouTube is also a great resource for these exercises.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, only your reflex matters in improving block starts.  I suggest doing as many starts as you can, and having someone time you with a stopwatch. Try to be faster in leaving the blocks.  Being low initially helps in gaining speed, efficiently and swiftly leaving the blocks.